# Node app (meteor) do not accept XHR connections

Tags: ajax, node.js, meteor, xmlhttprequest

Have just moved old (but running on the RedHat OpenShift PaaS) node app (Meteor to be ohnest) into new Linux VPS box.

The problem is that node server seems to refuse (block,do not provide, do not service) the XHR type connections from browser directed to the port usally defined using the

```
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL
```

env variable.

As I understand it's used for Ajax like responsiveness build in the Meteor apps.

From the browser point of view, I just see failed XHR type connections to the DDP url.

Firewall seems to be set ok.

Http communication (port 80) works ok, so I can get the static part of the web page and even navigate to other static pages but no dynamic data /like db/.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put export before setting the environment variable.
Run this command and I hope that will solve your problem.

```
export DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL
```

Comment: I did not, I export DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL in the starting js script like that 'process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = "http://xx.yy.com:8000"'' What's more I can see the same port in the browser so it's working.

Comment: It should be like export DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=http://myweb.com:8000 
Make sure port is not used by any other server and remove the extra double inverted comma from the last.

Answer (score 0):

So it was just the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL setting. Once the app was deployed to the RH OpenShift PaaS the value used there was :8000. My fault was I assumed it has to be the same everywhere. Changing it to :8080 (port used by node) made app working.

I just thought they have to be separate ports (one for www and one for DDP).